# How to wait for an animation to finish in viewDidDisappear?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to hide the navigation bar using animation before I let a UIViewController disappear. Therefore I have implemented the following:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{ 
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];     
    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    NSLog(@"animation finished");
    }];

     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The problem is that the viewWillDisappear will continue to execute and just return and the whole view will go away before the animation finishes. How can I stop the method from returning before the completion of the animation (where "animation finished" gets printed).

Comment: You can't animate that.  Maybe you're looking for the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method instead?

Comment: I don't want to use `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` because it animates differently in iOS 4 (slides away to the left) and iOS 5 (slides away towards the top). Anyhow, it doesn't matter because, putting `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` within the `viewWillDisappear` block will still mean that the method returns before the animation finishes. I think that maybe two threads are needed here?

Answer (score 2):

`viewWillDisappear:animated` is in essence a courtesy notification. It's just telling you what is imminent before it happens. You can't actually block or delay the disappearance of the view.

Your best solution would be to create a category on `UINavigationController` that creates methods such as (untested):

```
- (void)pushViewControllerAfterAnimation:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView transitionWithView:viewController.view
                      duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{ 
                        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];     
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"animation finished");
                        [self pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
                    }];
}

- (void)popViewControllerAfterAnimationAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.visibleViewController.view
                      duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{ 
                        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];     
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"animation finished");
                        [self popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
                    }];
}
```

You could then call these on instead of

`- (void)pushViewControllerAfterAnimation:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

and

`- (void)popViewControllerAfterAnimationAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

respectively.

Comment: Looks great :), although I'm not sure what happens when you use transitionWithView: with a curveEaseInOut option, never tried it like that.

Comment: I agree, I'm not totally sure either. The use of transitionWithView: comes from OP's original code, but I haven't tested it.